# How to intercept POST data with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am using this javascript function to send data to my php script (via POST) I am then using this information to retrieve data from my database and I would like to reuse the information retrieved in my JavaScript code.

Here is my code :

```
$(document).on("click", "#validerChoixDeCours", function() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'myFunctions.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      functionname: 'proposePA',
      arguments: clickedButtons
    },
    success: function() {
      // HERE I would like to inctercept the data that my php script put in myFunctions.php produces and use it to generate content;
    }
  });
});
```

So basically, when clicking on the button `#validerChoixDeCours`, my code sends some data to `myFunctions.php` which generates a response stored in a php variable and I want to use that response in my JS code.

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: What do you mean when you say you want to intercept the response? Do you need to set it somewhere in the page?

Comment: [`$.ajax()` | jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), [Ajax | jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/)

Comment: I need to handle it with my JS code

Answer (score 0):

Its actually quite easy!

```
$(document).on("click", "#validerChoixDeCours", function() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'myFunctions.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      functionname: 'proposePA',
      arguments: clickedButtons
    },
    success: function(e) {
      e contains the response from the php script
    }
  });
});
```

The first parameter of success contains the response from the request. so, in this case, the 'e' variable contains the output which you can use.

Comment: Please mark the awnser as correct so other people with similair questions know it is valid.  
Ooh and no problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add data variable

```
$(document).on("click", "#validerChoixDeCours", function() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'myFunctions.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      functionname: 'proposePA',
      arguments: clickedButtons
    },
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
    }
  });
});
```

make sure your server side code look like this

```
<?php
$output = "Any String or Array";

echo json_encode($output);

?>
```